# Transforming Map attribute into columns using Java, Spring and H2 database

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, h2, apache-commons

I'm trying to create a dynamic table in H2 database receiving the headers and the data from a .CSV file. My CSVModel contains a Map<String, Object> attributes and a Integer id attribute. But the H2 database does not allow add a Map object to his database.

I managed to create a method which gets the first line of the .CSV file and put on Map model attribute, providing the basis for the table header. How can I use this map to create the columns on H2 database?

**CSVModel class**

```
package com.br.aloi.planner.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity(name = "tbl_csv")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CSVModel implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;
  @javax.persistence.Transient
  private Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  public CSVModel() {

  }

  public Integer getId() {
     return id;
  }

  public Integer setId(Integer id) {
     return this.id = id;
  }

  public Map<String, Object> getAttributes() {
     return attributes;
  }

  public String getAttribute(String key) {
     return this.attributes.entrySet().stream().filter(s -> s.getKey().equals(key))
          .findFirst().get().getKey().toString();
  }

  public void setAttributes(String key, Object value) {
  attributes.put(key, value); }
 }
```

**CSVRepository class**

```
package com.br.aloi.planner.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.br.aloi.planner.model.CSVModel;

@Repository
public interface CSVRepository extends JpaRepository<CSVModel, Integer> {

}
```

**CSVService class.** **This class read the csv file and the headers, and save line by line in repository with .save command**

```
package com.br.aloi.planner.service;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.br.aloi.planner.model.CSVModel;
import com.br.aloi.planner.model.SalesmanModel;
import com.br.aloi.planner.repository.CSVRepository;

@Service
public class CSVService {

  @Autowired
  private CSVRepository repository;
    
  public void readCSVfile(InputStream in) {
     Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
     try {
        CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
             .withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim()
             .withAllowMissingColumnNames());
        CSVModel csvModel = new CSVModel();

        for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
          for (String header : csvRecord.getParser().getHeaderNames()) {
             csvModel.setAttributes(header, csvRecord.get(header));
          }

          repository.save(csvModel);
          csvModel = new CSVModel();
        }
        csvParser.close();
     } catch (

     IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     }    
  }
}
```

**My CSVControlle class. This controller send the user to a upload page file, and after him choose the file, send the file to CSVService class to the upload on database.**

```
package com.br.aloi.planner.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.br.aloi.planner.service.CSVService;
import com.br.aloi.planner.service.CustomerService;
import com.br.aloi.planner.service.NeighborhoodService;
import com.br.aloi.planner.service.SalesmanService;
import com.google.maps.errors.ApiException;

@Controller
public class CSVController {

  @Autowired
  private CSVService csvService;
  @Autowired
  private CustomerService customerService;
  @Autowired
  private NeighborhoodService neighborhoodService;
  @Autowired
  private SalesmanService salesmanService;

  @GetMapping("/")
  public ModelAndView uploadFile(
        @RequestParam(value = "action", required = false) Optional<String> action) {
     ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
     mv.setViewName("/uploadFile");
     return mv;
  }

  @PostMapping("/saveUploadedFile")
  public ModelAndView saveUploadedFile(@RequestParam("destination") String destination,
        MultipartFile file) throws IOException, ApiException, InterruptedException {
     customerService.clearDB();
     salesmanService.clearDB();
     neighborhoodService.clearDB();
     csvService.readCSVfile(file.getInputStream());
     ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
     mv.setViewName("/planner");
     mv.addObject("csvModels", csvService.findAll());
     return mv;
  }    
}
```

**(EDITED) CSV FILE EXAMPLE**
[image: CSV FILE]

Comment: Please show an example of your CSV.

Comment: added in the end

Comment: My h2 database is only with a one column: ID, generated by h2.

Comment: You have marked the map as transient? That’s telling orm to ignore it. https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-persisting-maps

Comment: when i put the annotation Column instead Transient, the server not recognize the map variable.